# AngularJS ui-grid get filtered rows in despite of pagination

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angular-ui-grid

Is there any solution for get all filtered rows from ui-grid even we are using pagination? I know that there is a method

```
$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
```

which returns all visible rows on page. But this method doesn't help when filtered data is more then one page.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any Documentation about filter data so the way I used is fully manual.

Lets grab active filters we have:

```
function getGridUiFilters(){
     var filters_ = _.filter($scope.gridApi.grid.columns, function(_column){
          return _column.filter.term !== undefined && _column.filter.term !== null;
     });
      return filters_;    
}
```

Now we can get all grid data and filter it by using filters you defined in `columnDefs`:

```
function getFilteredDatagridIds(){
     var gridFilters = getGridUiFilters();

     var gridRows = $scope.gridApi.grid.rows;

     var dataRows = _.map(gridRows, function(_row){
           return _row.entity; // our object stored in row
     });

      var filteredDataRows = _.filter(dataRows, function(_row){
         var isMatch = true;

         angular.forEach(gridFilters, function (_filter) {
               // call 'condition' method  defined in 'columnDefs'          
               isMatch = isMatch &&  
                        _filter.filter.condition(_filter.filter.term, _row[_filter.field] );

              });

                    return isMatch;
                });

                return filteredDataRows;
            }
```

---

In my case `columnDefs` looks like:

```
columnDefs: [
                        {displayName: 'Meeting', field: 'name_obj',
                            enableSorting: true,
                            enableColumnMenu: false,
                            cellTemplate: meetingNameCellTemplate,
                            headerCellTemplate: meetingNameHeaderCellTemplate,
                            filter: {
                                condition: function (searchTerm, cellValue) {
                                    return cellValue.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }, ....
```

So I'm sure this example will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as you described above. Any other problem that I had it was that my grid could have multiple columns sorted and i need to ask for a certain element.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129218/ui-grid-get-sorted-items-with-pagination) and an example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYNpEQNTeaAlCqWVPJoV?p=preview)

Below you can find the JS code that does that :

```
var app = angular.module('stefanz', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'UIGridCustom', '$http', function($scope, UIGridCustom, $http){
  // A part of data copied from ui-grid demos 
  var data = [{"name": "Ethel Price", "gender": "female", "company": "Enersol" },{"name": "Claudine Neal", "gender": "female", "company": "Sealoud" },{"name": "Beryl Rice", "gender": "female", "company": "Velity" },{"name": "Wilder Gonzales", "gender": "male", "company": "Geekko" },{"name": "Georgina Schultz", "gender": "female", "company": "Suretech" },{"name": "Carroll Buchanan", "gender": "male", "company": "Ecosys" },{"name": "Valarie Atkinson", "gender": "female", "company": "Hopeli" },{"name": "Schroeder Mathews", "gender": "male", "company": "Polarium" },{"name": "Lynda Mendoza", "gender": "female", "company": "Dogspa" },{"name": "Sarah Massey", "gender": "female", "company": "Bisba" },{"name": "Robles Boyle", "gender": "male", "company": "Comtract" },{"name": "Evans Hickman", "gender": "male", "company": "Parleynet" },{"name": "Dawson Barber", "gender": "male", "company": "Dymi" }];
  var colDefs = [{
    label: "name",
    name: "name"
  }, {
    label: "gender",
    name: "gender"
  }, {
    label: "company",
    name: "company"
  }];

  // Call the service for init
  var gridOptions = $scope.gridOptions = UIGridCustom.createGridOptions(data, colDefs); 

  gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(api) {
    $scope.gridApi = api;
  }

  $scope.getItemPage = function(name) {
    UIGridCustom.jumpToGridItem($scope.gridApi, name); 
  }

}]);


app.service('UIGridCustom', ['uiGridConstants', 'utils', function(uiGridConstants, utils){
        var defaultGridOptions = {
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            enablePaginationControls: false,
            paginationPageSize: 5,
            multipleSorting: true
        };

        // Each columns sort rule
        // Position 0 from columnsOrder sorts position 0 from columnDefs and so on
        // Could be overwritten into columnDefs
        // Docs : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions
        var defaultColSort = [];

        //1st column default sorting
        defaultColSort[{
            sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 }
        }];

        // For sorting 2nd column
        // defaultColSort[1] = {
        //     sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 }
        // };


        this.createGridOptions = function (gridData, columnDefs, stefanzGridOpts) {
            // Overwrite defaults with custom passed options for grid
            var stefanzGridOpts = typeof stefanzGridOpts !== 'undefined' ? stefanzGridOpts : {};
            var gridOptions = angular.extend({}, defaultGridOptions, stefanzGridOpts);

            // Force sorting following the default/custom column sort
            for(var i = 0; i < defaultColSort.length; i++)
                columnDefs[i] = angular.extend({}, defaultColSort[i], columnDefs[i]);

            // Grid init
            gridOptions.data = gridData;
            gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
            return gridOptions;
        };


        this.jumpToGridItem = function(api, name) {
            var idx = 0;
            var page = 0;

            var sorting = prepareCriteria(api.grid.getColumnSorting());
            var data = dataObjectSort(prepareRows(api.grid.rows), sorting);

            entry = getEntryByName(data, name);
            idx = data.indexOf(entry) + 1;

            if (!idx)
                return false;


            // Calculate the page where the element exists
            page = Math.ceil(idx/api.grid.options.paginationPageSize);

            alert(name + 'is found on page ' + page);
            // Jump to page
            api.pagination.seek(page);

        };

        // Takes the row's entity and put in a new array as a top-level item
        // Userful for further data handling 
        var prepareRows = function(rows) {
            if (rows.length == 0)
                return false;

            var preparedRows = [];
            rows.forEach(function(row){
                // Do not need to handle the rows that are not in current filter (hidden)
                if (row.visible == false)
                    return true;

                preparedRows.push(row.entity);
            });
            return preparedRows;
        };

        // We are comparing whole enter and as a parameter we are sending a name
        var getEntryByName = function(data, searchedName) {
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i]['name'] == searchedName)
              return data[i];
          }

          return false;
        }

        var dataObjectSort = function(data, criteria) {
            return data.sort(utils.dynamicSortMultiple(criteria));
        };

        var prepareCriteria = function(colSorting) {
            var sorting = [];
            var fields = [];

            // Take just needed fields
            colSorting.forEach(function(column){
                sorting.push({
                    field: column.field,
                    direction: column.sort.direction,
                    priority: column.sort.priority
                })
            });

            // Sort criterias by priority - UI grid works like this
            // Reason : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_sort
            sorting.sort(function(a, b){
              if (a.priority < b.priority) return -1;
              else if (a.priority > b.priority) return 1;
              else return 0;
            });

            // Prepare fields for sorting 
            sorting.forEach(function(sort){
                // Dymanic sort (above) needs "-" sign for descendent direction
                if (sort.direction != uiGridConstants.ASC)
                    sort.field = '-' + sort.field;
                fields.push(sort.field);
            });

            return fields;
        };
}]);

// Keep utils methods into a separate service
// Here all sorting methods will appear
app.service('utils', function(){

    function getJsonValue(obj, path) {
        if (!path || path == '') 
            return obj;

        path = path.split('.');

        var len = path.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
            var prop = path[i].split(/\[([^\]]+)]/); // indication[4] => [indication, 4]; indication => [indication]

            if (prop.length == 1) {
                obj = obj[prop[0]];
            } else {
                obj = obj[prop[0]][prop[1]];
            }
        }

        var prop = path[len - 1].split(/\[([^\]]+)]/); // indication[4] => [indication, 4]; indication => [indication]
        if (prop.length == 1) {
            return obj[prop[0]];
        } else {
            if (prop.length == 2) {
                return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]];
            } else {
                if(prop.length ==3) {
                    return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]]; // this is a hack!
                } else {
                    return obj[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[3]]; // this is a hack!
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript/4760279#4760279
    function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if(property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a,b) {
            var aInsensitive = getJsonValue(a, property).toLowerCase();
            var bInsensitive = getJsonValue(b, property).toLowerCase();
            var result = (aInsensitive < bInsensitive) ? -1 : (aInsensitive > bInsensitive) ? 1 : 0;
            return result * sortOrder;
        }
    };

    function dynamicSortMultiple(props) {
        return function (obj1, obj2) {
            var i = 0, result = 0, numberOfProperties = props.length;
            while(result === 0 && i < numberOfProperties) {
                result = dynamicSort(props[i])(obj1, obj2);
                i++;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    return {
        getJsonValue: function(obj, path) {
            return getJsonValue(obj, path);
        },
        dynamicSort: function(property) {
            return dynamicSort(property);
        },
        dynamicSortMultiple: function(props) {
            return dynamicSortMultiple(props);
        }
    }

});
```